# How to get client's IP in NanoHTTPD (HTTP server)?

Tags: java, http, ip, nanohttpd

I'm programming a simple web browser depending on [NanoHTTPD](http://elonen.iki.fi/code/nanohttpd/) project and it's required to get number of visitors using the IP address.

Are there any ways to get the client IP using NanoHTTPD?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In NanoHTTPD.java, find the private class HTTPSession object.

Inside this is public void run(). Find the following line and add the second line after it.

```
decodeHeader(hin, pre, parms, header);
header.put("IPAddress", mySocket.getInetAddress().getHostAddress());
```

Now inside your serve function, you can just reference the IPAddress header to get the client's ip address.

I know the answer is probably too  late to help you, but hopefully it'll help others searching for the same thing.

Comment: how to reference it in serve function??

Comment: The NanoHTTPD version from Oct 18, 2013 on have it in the header information of the serve method. Use header.get("remote-addr") to access it.

Answer (score 2):

I found in the latest master branch, you can get the client ip address by header "http-client-ip" in the IHTTPSession session object.